# combine 2 columns from 2 tables into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have tab1 with following data

```
ID |  Name
1  |   furniture
2  |   Electronic
3  |   Books
```

tab2 as

foreignkeyID |  Name

```
1            |   sofa
1            |   chair
3            |   c#
3            |   sql
2            |   fan
2            |   tv
```

I want result set as

```
Name
furniture
sofa
chair
Electronic
FAN
TV
Books
c#
sql
```

I achieve the above result set using cursor ,while loop ,how will i get the desire output without looping

Answer (score 4):

try this,

```
Declare @tab1 table(ID int,  Name varchar(40))
insert into @tab1 values(1 ,'furniture')
,(2,'Electronic'),(3,'Books')

declare @tab2 table(foreignkeyID int, Name varchar(40))
insert into @tab2 values
(1,'sofa'),
(1,'chair'),(3,'c#'),(3,'sql'),
(2,'fan'),(2,'tv')

select name from
(select 1 rn, id, name from @tab1
union all
select 2, foreignkeyID, name from @tab2
)t4
order by  id,rn
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) could do the job. Or for something a bit different, you can use a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Normally recursive CTEs are used when there are multiple levels but there's no reason why you can't use the same technique for just 1 level.

```
declare @t1 table (id int, category varchar(100))
insert @t1 values (1, 'furniture'), (2, 'Electronic'), (3, 'Books')

declare @t2 table (id int, item varchar(100))
insert @t2 values (1, 'sofa'), (1, 'chair'), (3, 'c#'), (3, 'sql'), (2, 'fan'), (2, 'tv')

-- Approach 1 : UNION

; with cte as (
    select
        id, 0 as level, category as name
    from
        @t1
    union all
    select
        id, 1 as level, item as name
    from
        @t2
)
select
    name
from
    cte
order by
    id, level

-- Approach 2 : Recursive CTE

; with cte as (
    select
        id, category as name, 0 as level
    from @t1
    union all
    select 
        t2.id, t2.item, level + 1 
    from
        @t2 t2 
            inner join cte on cte.id = t2.id
                         and level = 0
)
select
    name
from
    cte
order by
    id, level
```